# If statement is not working in php

Tags: php, if-statement, get

This code is not working well

How can I fix it ? :)

i got error on this line

> if($_GET["id"] === "2")

Here's is the code

```
<?php if($_GET["id"] === "1")
    print $link1

if($_GET["id"] === "2")
    print $link2
```

> $link1 = "Link1";
>
> $link2 = "Link2";

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What error do you get?

Comment: but I think `$link1 = "Link1";` should be written before `if`? also `print_r($_GET)` to see what is there

Comment: do you really want to be compareing types?

Comment: Probably missing semicolons after the echo statements

Comment: @AmalMurali murali Sometimes u see link like this [link](http://example.com/example.php?id=1) when you change the id number u get another code in the page,, i want to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to go ahead and clean it up a bit, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but I can assume it is supposed to look like:

```
<?php

$link1 = "Link1";
$link2 = "Link2";

if($_GET["id"] == "1") {
 print $link1;
}
if($_GET["id"] == "2") {
 print $link2;
}
```

Comment: Now working, Devon
Thanks :)
but there's something else
i want to put in link1 and link2 a JS code like

<script>top.location="http://www.website.com";</script>

How can i do it ? :)

Comment: You would want something like: `echo "<script>top.location=\"$link1\";</script>";` instead of `print $link1;`

Comment: Not working well,, Don't know why !
`<?php

$link1 = "http://www.facebook.com";
$link2 = "http://www.google.com";

if($_GET["id"] == "1") {
echo "<script>top.location=\"$link1\";</script>";
}
if($_GET["id"] == "2") {
echo "<script>top.location=\"$link2\";</script>";
}
?>`

Comment: @FadySaeed: You shouldn't anyway. Use a HTTP redirect instead of outputting script tags.

Comment: I tried to do so ,, but got error on the line
`echo <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=\"$link1\;">;`

Comment: i've done it,, it's now working `'<script>top.location="'.$link1.'";</script>';` .. **Thanks a lot Guys**

Answer (score 0):

=== check the type of the operators too. If you just want to compare the two strings use ==
The object returned by $_GET["id"] may not be of the same type as the String "1"

Answer (score 0):

**===** is an Identical compare operator, meaning that the items being compared must be of the same type.

```
$_GET["id"] === "2"
```

is TRUE if $_GET["id"] is equal to "2", and they are both strings.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php